# Battery to replace by adapter

Tags: audio

radio having DC 7.4 V 1000 mA battery, giving 3 hours back up play back. Now want to replace battery and directly on DC adapter and do not want back up, but plug and play. So what should be the adapter ratings?

Comment: The battery is 1000mA*h? I think 7.4V 1A power supply would work fine, though you may not need the whole amp of current rating.

Answer (score 1):

7.4V is probably a 2 cell lithium battery, and the voltage from those can actually be over 8V when fully charged.

7.5V is a common setting on adjustable power supplies and being close to the sticker voltage and within the normal voltage range of the battery should be ideal.

Assuming it's a radio receiver only (not a transmitter) it's power
requirements will be reasonably constant so it can be assumed that it wants about 333mA (1000mAh divided by 3 hours)

So a 7.5V DC supply of more than 333mA should be sufficient, I'd go for 500mA or more, to allow the volume to be turned up a bit if needed. too much mA capacity will not cause problems (not until ridiculous levels where the cable becomes too heavy etc).

Answer (score 0):

Use a DC adapter that is around 7.4 V ... be careful not too deviate too much from this, it is impossible to know what is the allowed range.

About the mA, this depends on how much the radio is requesting. The 1000 mA does not say much, this is how much the battery can deliver during its lifetime (or for one charge). It should be AT least the current the radio needs. For an adapter, too high mA is never a problem, too less it is. So better use a larger than smaller one. You probably can find the value if you use a multimeter and check the current draw.